# Is there any importance for Toe Rings in Islam?

Tags: history, women, sunnah

I was searching about importance of Toe Rings in Islam. They carry some importance in Hinduism. Married women wear it for various reasons. I also seen some Muslim women wearing them.

So I searched for some information in this. And [Askimam.org has a question](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/2957.html) regarding this.

> Is it permisable to wear toe-rings?
>
> Are toe-rings, nose rings etc permitted? What if they have origin in other religions like Hinduism? I wish to wear it as I like it, not for religious reason
>
> Answer:
>   There is no prohibition to wear nose or toe rings. However, it will be
>   prohibited if it has any significance in any other religion.
>
> and Allah Ta'ala Knows Best
>
> Mufti Ebrahim Desai

So the answer says there's no prohibition but didn't talk much about its importance in Islam.

When searched more, I found a book named *[The Perfect Wife (Stridharmapaddhati)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=DKbCwDXMP2wC&lpg=PR7&pg=PA101&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)*
By Tryambakayajvan (A book on Hindu practices though) which claims Toe Rings were originally a muslim ornament (emphasis mine).

> Altekar notes the conspicuous absence of the nose-ring in sculpture and painting throughout India before the Muslim invasions. **He concludes that it was originally a Muslim ornament** (1978:301 ff.; cf. PVK II.i.537).

Is there any kind of importance of Toe Rings in Islam?

Comment: Wearing a toe ring is permissible for women, there isn't any importance of it beyond that and the answer you link demonstrates this as well: as otherwise it should have said that it is mustahab (recommended) rather than saying that it is not prohibited.

Comment: @UmH If toe rings are related to Hinduism and someone may mistake the wearer to be a Hindu rather than a Muslim, then does not that make it makruh at the minimum? Isn't it similar to a Bindi of the Hindu lady?

Comment: @Ahmed It would be if they were a unique mark of non-muslims or were worn to imitate them. However that is very subjective and special case. More likely they are an item of common jewelry and adornment is permissible for a woman. For example Ibn Abi Hatim has [narrated](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8658/2566#p2) from Aisha about الفتخة - silver rings that are worn on the fingers of the feet.

Answer (score -1):

Actually false, whoever you are quuoting, nose ring is already mentioned by sri vaishnavas and shankaracharya who was born before or same century as the prophet.

And as for toe rings they are also present in valmiki ramayana.

As for muslim women any kind of permanent change on facial features is considered haram. Tattoos, rings or piercings.